# Is it possible to set the Foreign Key as Not Null in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle11g

First of all I wanna apologize if this question is duplicated. As far as I'm concerned, Oracle allows a Foreign Key to be NULL, but how can I enforce a Foreign Key to be Not Null in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add a `not null` constraint on that column, regardless of the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY mycolumn NUMBER /* or whatever type definition it has */ NOT NULL;
```